# How to send data from session beans to presentation tier?

Tags: java, design-patterns, ejb, n-tier-architecture

I develop a Java application with **4 tiers**: database (MySQL), persistence (JPA), business (POJOs similar to stateless session beans in EJB), presentation (Java Swing).

I decided to fully *decouple presentation and persistence tiers*. So all modifications to all data are done *through the business tier*. This way the presentation tier does not even know that entity classes exist. This also allows a session bean to have a better control over the data passed, because sometimes a session bean needs to *validate or convert values* received from the presentation before changing the entities.

However, sometimes a session bean needs to send a big amount of information (like a list of entities with lots of properties) to a caller. And this becomes complicated because according to the design I adopted session bean needs to unwrap all those entities into something else. I tried to convert the list of entities into *a list of arrays* (where each member of an array correspond to a property in the entity), but this seems to be so flawed, error-prone and inefficient to me.

What would be the right way to send data over to the presentation? Does the concept of hiding the entities behind the session beans make any sense at all? What is the common pattern in such applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common pattern is to use the JPA entities when they fit the bill (i.e. when they contain the data needed by the presentation tier, and when you don't need to fetch half of the database to return this data), and to use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects, which are just POJOs containing the required information) when the entities don't fit the bill.

Some prefer to only use DTOs, like you're doing. But DTOs should be real objects, with typed properties. Lists of arrays a nightmare to understand and maintain, do not offer any kind of type safety and compilation checks, and are not easily usable by the classical presentation tier technologies (JSP EL, etc.), which generally expect JavaBeans.

Comment: One issue with sending JPA entities to remote client is however that you are sending the technical PKs as well, not only business keys. Especially if the user is allowed to update the data you have to make sure the correct PKs are used (not manipulated) when you re-attach the entities. The DTOs make this issue more clear by only sending the data the user needs (which might involve business keys, but not surrogate PKs).

Comment: And what would prevent them to manipulate business keys? I don't see any difference here. BTW, there are lots of entities which don't have any business key.

Comment: PK = Primary Key. Yes, a detached entity is a good DTO. Just make sure to document, in each service method returning a detached entity, which associations are initialized and which are not.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the concept of hiding the entities behind the session beans make
>   any sense at all? What is the common pattern in such applications?

Yes, I recommend to send DTOs (design pattern; Data Transfer Object) instead of JPA entities if the client runs on a different JVM (remote).

The EJB design pattern you are probably looking for is: Service Facade
The goal is to provide coarse grained, client/ use case specific APIs.

Adam Bien wrote a book about Java EE 5/6 design patterns:
http://press.adam-bien.com/real-world-java-ee-patterns-rethinking-best-practices.htm

Only send as much data as the user can conveniently handle, e.g. using filtering or paging technics.

Comment: It's a bit strange for you to recomment DTOs and Adam Bien's book at the same time, since the page you linked to says: "Discussion of superfluous patterns and outdated best practices like [...] Data Transfer Objects"

Comment: Well, in the book remote EJBs were rather the exception than the rule. If you're writing a Web application where the web frontend is run in the same JVM, you're often better off with the the Gateway pattern, which uses attached JPA entities, rather than using DTOs. But if you are using remote EJBs or a Web Service (which defines the DTOs in WSDL/ XSD), I wouldn't recommend to use JPA entities.

Comment: Agreed. But the OP isn't using remote EJBs.

Comment: Well, the OP is talking about EJBs and Swing. So I guessed remote EJBs, since Web Services or other technologies weren't mentioned.